# Whatsapp: is there any possibility to turn off internet for a specific contact only?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I know there is an option to turn off internet access for entire whatsapp but i was wondering if there is a way to disable access for a specific chat completely?

What i am trying to accomplish by doing this? I am trying to modify contact details such as phone number without letting whatsapp to get refreshed or anything.

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a way to disable access for a specific chat completely?

Not directly. Maybe try blocking the contact temporarily when you update their details?

> What i am trying to accomplish by doing this? I am trying to modify contact details such as phone number without letting whatsapp to get refreshed or anything.

Currently not aware of a direct workaround for this. But can only suggest the workaround now.